# Assigning locally created array in function to globally defined array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with assigning arrays:

```
    var obj = [ {'id': 1, 'size': 'king' }, {'id':4, 'size': 'queen'} ];
    function modify(o){
      var result=[{'id': 1, 'size': 'king'}];
      o=result.slice();
    }
    modify(obj);
    document.write("result:" + JSON.stringify(obj)); //obj both 'king and queen'
```

I would like to have 'obj' filled with data from 'result' array, but this way does not work. It is possible to make the array empty and change its content like this:

```
    o.length=0;//obj is empty outside of the function
    o[1].id = 100;//id is changed outside of the function
```

I know I could do that by returning 'result' array and assigning it outside t 'obj', but there will be more such association in the function.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: After you modify the obj is the expected output 'king' only?

Comment: Yes, that is expectd output.

Comment: That's impossible. JavaScript does not have pass-by-reference. However, you could actually *modify* the passed array object - instead of overwriting it, change its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this if you want the assignment to take place in the function. You can change the content of obj and do the clean way of passing it as parameter:

```
var obj = [ {'id': 1, 'size': 'king' }, {'id':4, 'size': 'queen'} ];
function modify(o){
  var result=[{'id': 1, 'size': 'king'}];
  o.length = 0;
  o.push.apply(o,result); // push every element from result
}
modify(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Or you can change the reference to something else. In this case you have to use the actual variable, not a parameter to your function:

```
var obj = [ {'id': 1, 'size': 'king' }, {'id':4, 'size': 'queen'} ];
function modifyObj(){
  var result=[{'id': 1, 'size': 'king'}];
  obj = result.slice();
}
modify();
console.log(obj);
```

A little improvement on the second method is to keep your array in an object, but that changes the way you need to access it in the rest of the code:

```
var container = { 
  obj : [ {'id': 1, 'size': 'king' }, {'id':4, 'size': 'queen'} ] 
};
function modify(container, key){
  var result=[{'id': 1, 'size': 'king'}];
  container[key] = result.slice();
}
modify(container, 'obj');
console.log(container.obj);
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't name the second function `modify` any more…

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, i updated its name to indicate the fact that it changes a variable in the outer scope. I also tweaked the last idea to allow the "name" of the object to be passed as parameter.

Comment: Oops, it actually does *modify* the variable… I had imagined a `return` to be in there like in the other answers - but thanks for the clarification :-)